# Execute Perl Regular Expression on all zip files unix

Tags: perl

I have collections of zip files in that i have some xml data.On that data i want to execute Perl regular expression from command line .But the command is only working on non zipped files and for zipped file it is not wokring.

```
 perl -ne '/ID:([0-9.]+).+Test=\"([\d\w.-\s]+)\"/ and print "$1 $2\n"' data.log.gz  | sort -nr | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Sample XML structure:

```
ABC ID:12342132: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><a Test="ABC"></a>
```

Comment: Need unzip data before test `zcat data.log.gz | perl .... | ...`

Comment: We need more XML. But the answer is 'don't use a regex; use a parser'.

Comment: That `ABC ID:12342132` at the start of the data means that what you have there isn't XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zipped files won't contain the data that you want in a format that you can easily parse with Perl. You need to unzip them first. But the Unix command `zcat` can you that on the fly for you.

```
$ zcat data.log.gz | perl ...
```

Comment: I would expect a @Developer to understand what a bad problem report "this is not working" is. Please update your question to include exactly what you tried and exactly what unexpected behaviour you saw.

Comment: @Developer: Interesting that you said "this is not working" but then accepted it as an answer with no further explanation.

Comment: I was not providing required data in correct format.So i got the issue then i used your command and it worked for me